# Issues using Extension Maven Plugin

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml, xwiki

I've followed this [tutorial](https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/FAQ/How%20to%20generate%20a%20XIP%20file%20for%20an%20Extension%3F) to create an XIP of jira to be able to be installed to a offline xwiki deployment. I was successful in getting maven to build the XIP for jira; however, when I try to recreate this process with another extension, in this case [MediaWiki](https://github.com/xwiki-contrib/mediawiki), I get an unknown packaging error.

> [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
> [ERROR] Unknown packaging: xip @ line 30, column 14
> [WARNING] Reporting configuration should be done in  section, not in maven-site-plugin  as reportPlugins parameter. @
> @
> [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR]   The project org.xwiki.contrib.mediawiki:mediawiki-xml-xip:1.13.5 (/home/administrator/mediawiki/mediawiki-xml-xip/pom.xml) has 1 error
> [ERROR]     Unknown packaging: xip @ line 30, column 14
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException

This error is thrown after this DEBUG line.

> Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging xip from ClassRealm[project>org.xwiki.contrib.mediawiki:mediawiki-xml-xip:1.13.5, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

My pom.xml for the mediawiki-xml extension, that I am trying to build to an XIP looks like this.

```
<!--
 * See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for additional
 * information regarding copyright ownership.
 *
 * This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
 * under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of
 * the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This software is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this software; if not, write to the Free
 * Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA
 * 02110-1301 USA, or see the FSF site: http://www.fsf.org.
-->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.xwiki.contrib.mediawiki</groupId>
    <artifactId>mediawiki</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.5</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>mediawiki-xml-xip</artifactId>
  <name>MediaWiki - XIP</name>
  <packaging>xip</packaging>
  <description>XIP for offline installation of MediaWiki XML</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.xwiki.contrib.mediawiki</groupId>
      <artifactId>mediawiki-xml</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.xwiki.commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>xwiki-commons-tool-extension-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${commons.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <coreExtensions>
              <!-- We exclude what is already in the XWiki Standard WAR -->
              <coreExtension>
                <groupId>org.xwiki.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>xwiki-platform-distribution-war-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
              </coreExtension>
            </coreExtensions>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I know that the Extension Maven Plugin has something to do with my issue, I'm not sure if I need to download something else or move the location of my pom. This pom worked perfectly fine with jira, no changes where made on the build portion of the pom when I copied it over.

Help is greatly appreciated as I am not well versed in Maven. Thanks again!

Comment: You've only got the plugin in pluginManagement, which configures it but doesn't "instantiate" it.

Comment: which version of maven are you using? I get a similar message but only as a warning with maven 3.8.3. Also you need to add some repositories to your `settings.xml` as explained in https://dev.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Community/Building/#HInstallingMaven